# How to store different sets of text in one single variable using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am building a simple program using Python3 on MacOS, to scrap all the lyrics of an artist in one single variable. Although I am able to correctly iterate through different URL's (each Url is a song from this artist) and have the output that I want being printed, I am struggling to be able to store all the different songs in one single variable.

I've tried different approaches, trying to store it in a list, dictionary, dictionary inside a list, etc. but it didn't work out. I've also read Beautifulsoup documentation and several forums without success.

I am sure this should be something very simple. This is the code that I am running:

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://www.metrolyrics.com/notorious-big-albums-list.html")
c = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")

albums = soup.find("div", {'class' : 'grid_8'})


for page in albums.find_all('a', href=True, alt=True):
    d = {}
    r = requests.get(a['href'])
    c = r.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")
    song = soup.find_all('p', {'class':'verse'})
    title = soup.find_all('h1')

    for item in title:
        title = item.text.replace('Lyrics','')
        print("\n",title.upper(),"\n")

    for item in song:
        song = item.text
        print(song)
```

When running this code, you get the exact output that I would like to have stored in a single variable.

I've been struggling with this for days so I would really appreciate some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how you should store data in one variable.
This can be JSON or similar by using a python dictionary.

```
a = dict()
#We create a instance of a dict. Same as a = {}.

a[1] = 'one' 
#This is how a basic dictionary works. There is a key and a value.

a[2] = {'two':'the number 2'}

#Now our Key is normal, however, our value is another dictionary. 

print(a)
#This is how we access the dict inside the dict.
print(a[2]['two'])
# first key [2] (gives us {'two':'the number 2'} we access value inside it [2]['two']")
```

You'll be able to apply this knowledge to your algorithm.

Use the album as the first key `all['Stay strong'] = {'some-song':'text_heavy'}`

I also recommend making a function since you're re-using code.

for instance, the request and then parsing using bs4

```
def parser(url):
    make_req = request.get(url).text #or .content
    return BeautifulSoup(make_req, 'html.parser')
```

A good practice for software developement is so called **DRY** (Don't repeat yourself) since readability counts and as opposed to **WET** (Waste everyones time, Write Everything Twice).

*Just something to keep in mind.*

Answer (score 0):

I made it!!

I wasn't able to store the output in a variable, but I was able to write a txt file storing all the content which is even better. This is the code I used:

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('nBIGsongs.txt', 'a') as f:

    r = requests.get("http://www.metrolyrics.com/notorious-big-albums-list.html")
    c = r.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")

    albums = soup.find("div", {'class' : 'grid_8'})


    for a in albums.find_all('a', href=True, alt=True):
        r = requests.get(a['href'])
        c = r.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")
        song = soup.find_all('p', {'class':'verse'})
        title = soup.find_all('h1')

        for item in title:
            title = item.text.replace('Lyrics','')
            f.write("\n" + title.upper() + "\n")

        for item in song:
            f.write(item.text)

f.close()
```

I would still love to hear if there are other better approaches.

Thanks!